# Customization points in Eigen library

Tags: c++, templates, eigen, eigen3, argument-dependent-lookup

I am trying to implement a matrix-free function to use with conjugate gradient in `Eigen`. My matrix function is basically an application of several matrices consecutively to a vector so I prefer to implement my own matrix object and do this operations on my own so.

There is a nice tutorial on `Eigen`s webpage about how to achieve this:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__MatrixfreeSolverExample.html

This approach requires opening up `Eigen::internal` namespace to add some specializations for my own matrix object. AFAIK, writing stuff in others library namespaces is a bad practice and it should be implemented using customization points.

Is it possible to implement this using customization points? Is `Eigen` for this matter wrong?

Comment: Not all customizations can be phrased as ADL calls…

Comment: **Specializing** "stuff" in other libraries namespaces is not bad style per se. Especially, if the library encourages you to do that. I vote to close this as opinion-based.